# Why can't I create this table in MySQL? ERROR 1005 (HY000)

Tags: mysql, database

Error message:

> ERROR 1005 (HY000) at line __: Can't create table 'doanv.ENROLLED' (errno: 150)
>   Bye

Table `STUDENT`, `COURSE`, `PROF` are created successfully. Table `ENROLLED` and `TEACHING` can't be created. What did I do wrong?

```
CREATE TABLE STUDENT
(sID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
sFName VARCHAR(20),
sLName VARCHAR(20));

CREATE TABLE COURSE
(cID VARCHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
cName VARCHAR(20),
cr INTEGER);

CREATE TABLE PROF
(pID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
pFName VARCHAR(20),
pLName VARCHAR(20));

CREATE TABLE ENROLLED
(sID INTEGER NOT NULL,
cID VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (sID, cID),
FOREIGN KEY (sID) REFERENCES STUDENT,
FOREIGN KEY (cID) REFERENCES COURSE);

CREATE TABLE TEACHING
(pID INTEGER NOT NULL,
cID VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (pID, cID),
FOREIGN KEY (pID) REFERENCES PROF,
FOREIGN KEY (cID) REFERENCES COURSE);
```

Comment: You can leave the MYSQL out of the title, the mysql tag is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL you need to specify the columns being referred to.
You can get away with leaving out the **(sID)** and the **(cID)** in some other implementations of SQL.

```
CREATE TABLE ENROLLED
(sID INTEGER NOT NULL,
cID VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (sID, cID),
FOREIGN KEY (sID) REFERENCES STUDENT(sID),
FOREIGN KEY (cID) REFERENCES COURSE(cID));
```

Answer (score 0):

Foreign key references need the key being referenced:

```
CREATE TABLE ENROLLED (
    sID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    cID VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (sID, cID),
    FOREIGN KEY (sID) REFERENCES STUDENT(sID),
-----------------------------------------^
    FOREIGN KEY (cID) REFERENCES COURSE(cID)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

> "Why can't I create table in mySQL? ERROR 1005 (HY000)"
>   `ERROR 1005 (HY000) at line __: Can't create table 'doanv.ENROLLED' (errno: 150)`

---

From the [MySQL - FOREIGN KEY Constraints Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html):

> If you re-create a table that was dropped, it must have a definition that conforms to the foreign key constraints referencing it. It must have the correct column names and types, and it must have indexes on the referenced keys, as stated earlier. **If these are not satisfied, MySQL returns Error 1005 and refers to Error 150 in the error message, which means that a foreign key constraint was not correctly formed.** Similarly, if an ALTER TABLE fails due to Error 150, this means that a foreign key definition would be incorrectly formed for the altered table.

You left out the foreign key references in your sample code; try this instead:

```
CREATE TABLE STUDENT
(sID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
sFName VARCHAR(20),
sLName VARCHAR(20));

CREATE TABLE COURSE
(cID VARCHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
cName VARCHAR(20),
cr INTEGER);

CREATE TABLE PROF
(pID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
pFName VARCHAR(20),
pLName VARCHAR(20));

CREATE TABLE ENROLLED
(sID INTEGER NOT NULL,
cID VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (sID, cID),
FOREIGN KEY (sID) REFERENCES STUDENT(sID),
FOREIGN KEY (cID) REFERENCES COURSE(cID));

CREATE TABLE TEACHING
(pID INTEGER NOT NULL,
cID VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (pID, cID),
FOREIGN KEY (pID) REFERENCES PROF(pID),
FOREIGN KEY (cID) REFERENCES COURSE(cID));
```